# Are conditional transitions possible with ngAnimate?

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-ui-router, ng-animate

I have setup an animation in my application on ngView using ngAnimate. Every time there is a state change, the next view slides in from the **right**.

I would like to be able to reverse this, so that in some instances, the view slides in from the **left** (if the user is going *back*).

Since the only classes offered are `.ng-enter`, `.ng-leave`, and `.*-active`, what are my options? Is this even possible?

[Here's a CodePen](https://codepen.io/drewwyatt/pen/jbMKZz), **OR** see my sample code here:

**html**

```
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="DemoController as vm">
    <div ui-view class="foo"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
html,
[ui-view] {
 background: yellow; 
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}

div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

[ui-view].ng-enter,
[ui-view].ng-leave {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
    transition:all .5s ease-in-out;
}

[ui-view].ng-enter {
  opacity: 0;
  transform:translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
  /*transform:scale3d(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);*/
}

[ui-view].ng-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
  transform:translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  /*transform:scale3d(1, 1, 1);*/
}

[ui-view].ng-leave {
  opacity: 1;
  transform:translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

[ui-view].ng-leave-active {
  opacity: 0;
  transform:translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
}
```

**javascript**

```
'use strict';

angular.module('app', ['ui.router', 'ngAnimate'])
.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/one');  
  $stateProvider
    .state('one', {
      url: '/one',
      template: '<div class="one"><h1>ONE!</h1><button ng-click="vm.two()">go to two</button></div>'
    })
    .state('two', {
      url: '/two',
      template: '<div class="two"><h1>TWO!</h1><button ng-click="vm.one()">go to one</button></div>'
    });;
})
.controller('DemoController', DemoController);

DemoController.$inject = ['$state'];
function DemoController($state) {
  this.one = function()  {
    $state.go('one');
  }

  this.two = function() {
    $state.go('two');
  }
}
```

Comment: Here is an un-elegant and not very flexible example of implementing what you seem to be looking for: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YyGjBa

Comment: @Asok this gives me an idea of where to start. Thanks!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not going to do all the leg work to code this but will provide suggested way to do it.

Will require you to check history within `$stateChangeStart` and compare path to the next path

Toggle a class on `ui-view` based on match or not

Then write a set of css rules that are more specific to that class

```
[ui-view].ng-enter.fromRightClass{}
```

Comment: this makes a lot of sense. thanks for the speedy reply. Is it possible to set classes on `ui-view` directly from `$stateChangeStart`, or will I need to set a boolean value on the controller or something, then do: `<div ui-view ng-class="{ fromRight: fromRight }"></div>`

Comment: could do it either way I think... if you actually manipulate the dom using `angular.element().addClass()` a digest wouldn't be needed